# self hosted gitlab CI/CD push registry to ECS service

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecs, docker-registry

I am using self hosted gitlab on ubuntu 16.04. I have successfully created ECS and services. now I want to deploy my microservice to aws ecs. I don't know how to push  my private registry docker image to ecs. I have gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
- build
- package
- deploy
variables:
GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"
DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
before_script:
#  - echo `pwd` # debug
#  - echo "$CI_BUILD_NAME, $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME $CI_BUILD_STAGE" # debug
- export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
- export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
- chmod +x gradlew

 cache:
 paths:
 - .gradle/wrapper
 - .gradle/caches

build:
 stage: build
 image: openjdk:8-jdk
tags:
 - tag
script:
 - ./gradlew assemble
artifacts:
 paths:
   - build/libs/*.jar
 expire_in: 1 week
 only:
- master

 docker-build:
 stage: package
tags:
- tag
script:
- docker build -t registry.gitlab.example.com/root/abc:latest .
- docker login registry.gitlab.example.com -u gitlab-ci-token -p xyz
- docker push registry.gitlab.example.com/root/abc:latest
deploy:
 tags:
  - tag
 script:

after_script:
 - echo "End CI"
```

External registry url in gitlab.rb file is:

```
registry.gitlab.example.com
```

but how to available this in ecs deployment?
I have public IP of ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably get the option to use ECR with ECS. To push to AWS ECS you need a URL; looks something like: xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.your-region.amazonaws.com/url .Then you can probably do something like the following in your gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  REPOSITORY_URL: your_url

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
    - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URL .
    - docker push $REPOSITORY_URL
  tags:
    - docker
```

Don't forget to make those env variable in the settings (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY). You might also want to install aws-cli in a `before-script`

Answer (score 0):

Check also if [GitLab 13.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/08/22/gitlab-13-3-released/#ecs-task-definition-from-local-json) (August 2020) could help in your case:

> ### ECS task definition from local JSON
>
> Today, GitLab’s ECS deployment template updates existing task definitions that are already defined in your attached AWS account. It’s also common to update your task-definition as part of your GitLab flow.
>
> Now, you can update the JSON task definition in your local repository and push it knowing the task will get appropriately created in the AWS account, improving your standard development flow.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/#deploy-your-application-to-the-aws-elastic-container-service-ecs) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/222618).

See [this video as an example](https://www.youtube.com/embed/HxBUjriLK3U?rel=0).

---

Also, with [GitLab 13.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/11/22/gitlab-13-6-released/#create-job-to-stop-ecs-review-apps) (November 2020)

> ### Create job to stop ECS review Apps
>
> We recently added support for AWS ECS so you can use it as a deployment target for Auto DevOps.
> However, review apps for ECS targets weren’t automatically stopped.
>
> To rectify this, the `Deploy_ECS` template has been extended to automatically stop review apps as part of the Auto DevOps flow so that resources don’t go to waste.
> This ensures a similar experience for Auto DevOps users deploying to ECS and those using Kubernetes, where things work automatically without the need to manually stop and keep track of review apps.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_6/ecs_stop_review.png -- Create job to stop ECS review Apps]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_deployment/#deploy-your-application-to-the-aws-elastic-container-service-ecs) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/218167).